# Why could an extra back-slash appears in javascript in outsystems?

Tags: javascript, outsystems

we use the autocomplete component from RichWidgets and we get extra back-slash in the javascript which causes a bug in the autocomplete.

autocomplete JavaScript code tries to split the bulk of rows into items in the autocomplete list but the extra back-slash interrupt the split (js method from functioning well.

although we use the same component in another module (where it works perfectly without the extra back-slash) referencing to same RichWidgets but we still

---

update:
this is only when we use Arabic language, it works fine in english.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, it's difficult to answer, but if it only happens with the AR locale then it might be the case that there are translations defined for those strings that are causing the issue.

Check if setting the behavior of those strings to *not translate* makes any difference.